# Incorrect syntax near 'RETURN'. when trying to return an image

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return an image, using this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getDiverSignature (@id int) 
RETURNS image
return 
select diver_signature 
from Diver 
WHERE diver_number = @id 

GO
```

When i added the image to the Diver table i used:
    BulkColumn 
    FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\sign5.jpg', Single_Blob) as img

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how return works. Either you return a result set (in which case you would use just the `select` and not the `return`), or you have to return a single value, e.g.:

```
declare @ret image;

select @ret = diver_signature ...;

return @ret;
```

Comment: tried:


`CREATE FUNCTION getDiverSignature (@id int) 
RETURNS image 
as
BEGIN
 DECLARE @img image
    select @img = diver_signature 
from Diver 
WHERE diver_number = @id 
    return @img
END
GO`

and got this error: The image data type is invalid for return values.

Comment: @user3885474 Well, that sounds like a pretty understandable response - you can't return `image`, as simmple as that. Perhaps using `varbinary(max)` instead would work? Or revising your application design? :D

Comment: Is there a way to convert from varbinary(max) to image?

Comment: @user3885474 Why? You can use it in the same methods etc. `text` and `image` are a bit special types, they're quite limited.

Comment: because i have to use an image field, I'm not allowed to change it to varbinary(max).
So if i can return from the function only a varbinary(max), there isn't a way to insert it into my image field?

Comment: I have altered many columns from image to varbinary(max). You should be able to do it in place and not lose any functionality or suffer any data corruption.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that converting your scalar function to an inline table valued function should provide some added performance gains.